# WordPress Multisite VMware copy for dev use not allowing loggin

Tags: multisite, logging

New job and new project. I inherited a WordPress Multisite were the developers were working on the live site. Thinking I would be the smart new guy. I asked the sysadmin to make a VM copy, assign a new IP and domain name.

Now I can't log into the new system to update the settings. It redirects me to the original site to log in.  If I go to a subpage does the same. checked the htaccess file, wp-config.php file didn't see any redirects and I replaced the old with the new domain in the wp-config file.

Changed the domain in the wp_blogs, wp_domain_mapping, wp_options , wp_site and wp_sitemeta.  Nothing changed.  Its redirects before even showing a page.

Not a way to start a new project. Thanks for any help, pointers and guidance.

Comment: Did you update both the `siteurl` and `home` in the `wp_options` DB table? Also, check your `wp-config.php` file for the `DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE`.

Comment: I did update the wp_options table and the wp-config file. It seems to be redirecting even before it running any code. But the htaccess doesn't have a redirect unless i am looking at the wrong one.

Comment: Usually there's only one `.htaccess` file, in the site's root directory. Check your `wp-admin` directory for a `.htaccess` file there -- it could be the issue.

Comment: no .htaccess in the wp-admin directory